# Error in NMI pod after adding and installing Bitnami External DNS via Terraform and Helm - No AzureIdentityBinding found for pod

Tags: azure, terraform, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, external-dns

I am struggling to get the azureIdentity for ExternalDNS bound and get DNS entries into our zone(s).

> Key error:  I0423 19:27:52.830107       1 mic.go:610] No AzureIdentityBinding found for pod default/external-dns-84dcc5f68c-cl5h5 that matches selector: external-dns. it will be ignored
> Also, no azureAssignedIdentity is created since there is no match for the pod and selector/aadpodidbinding.

I'm building IaaC using Terraform, Helm, Azure, Azure AKS, VSCODE, and so far, three Kubernetes add-ons - aad pod identity, application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress, and Bitnami external-dns.

Since the identity isn't being bound, an azureAssignedIdentity isn't being created and ExternalDNS isn't able to put records into our DNS zone(s).

The names and aadpodidbindings seem correct.  I've tried passing in fullnameOverride in the Terraform kubectl_manifest provider for the Helm install of Bitnami ExternalDNS.  I've tried suppressing the suffixes on ExternalDNS names and labels.  I've tried editing the Helm and Kubernetes YAML on the cluster itself to try to force a binding.  I've tried using the AKS user managed identity which is used for AAD Pod Identity and is located in the cluster's nodepools resource group.  I've tried letting the Bitnami ExternalDNS configure and add an azure.json file, and I've also done so manually prior to adding and installing ExternalDNS.  I've tried assigning the managed identity to the VMSS of the AKS cluster.

Thanks!

JBP

```js
PS C:\Workspace\tf\HelmOne> kubectl logs pod/external-dns-84dcc5f68c-542mv
: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '404'. Response body: getting assigned identities for pod default/external-dns-84dcc5f68c-542mv in CREATED state failed after 16 attempts, retry duration [5]s, error: <nil>. Check MIC pod logs for identity assignment errors\n"
time="2021-04-24T19:57:30Z" level=debug msg="Retrieving Azure DNS zones for resource group: one-hi-sso-dnsrg-tf."
time="2021-04-24T20:06:02Z" level=error msg="azure.BearerAuthorizer#WithAuthorization: Failed to refresh the Token for request to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/8fb55161-REDACTED-3400b5271a8c/resourceGroups/one-hi-sso-dnsrg-tf/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnsZones?api-version=2018-05-01: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '404'. Response body: getting assigned identities for pod default/external-dns-84dcc5f68c-542mv in CREATED state failed after 16 attempts, retry duration [5]s, error: <nil>. Check MIC pod logs for identity assignment errors\n"
time="2021-04-24T20:06:02Z" level=debug msg="Retrieving Azure DNS zones for resource group: one-hi-sso-dnsrg-tf."



PS C:\Workspace\tf\HelmOne> kubectl logs pod/aad-pod-identity-nmi-vtmwm
I0424 20:07:22.400942       1 server.go:196] status (404) took 80007557875 ns for req.method=GET reg.path=/metadata/identity/oauth2/token req.remote=10.0.8.7
E0424 20:08:44.427353       1 server.go:375] failed to get matching identities for pod: default/external-dns-84dcc5f68c-542mv, error: getting assigned identities for pod default/external-dns-84dcc5f68c-542mv in CREATED state failed after 16 attempts, retry duration [5]s, error: <nil>. Check MIC pod logs for identity assignment errors
I0424 20:08:44.427400       1 server.go:196] status (404) took 80025612263 ns for req.method=GET reg.path=/metadata/identity/oauth2/token req.remote=10.0.8.7



PS C:\Workspace\TF\HelmOne>  kubectl logs pod/aad-pod-identity-mic-86944f67b8-k4hds
I0422 21:05:11.298958       1 main.go:114] starting mic process. Version: v1.7.5. Build date: 2021-04-02-21:14
W0422 21:05:11.299031       1 main.go:119] --kubeconfig not passed will use InClusterConfig
I0422 21:05:11.299038       1 main.go:136] kubeconfig () cloudconfig (/etc/kubernetes/azure.json)
I0422 21:05:11.299205       1 main.go:144] running MIC in namespaced mode: false
I0422 21:05:11.299223       1 main.go:148] client QPS set to: 5. Burst to: 5
I0422 21:05:11.299243       1 mic.go:139] starting to create the pod identity client. Version: v1.7.5. Build date: 2021-04-02-21:14
I0422 21:05:11.318835       1 mic.go:145] Kubernetes server version: v1.18.14
I0422 21:05:11.319465       1 cloudprovider.go:122] MIC using user assigned identity: c380##### REDACTED #####814b for authentication.
I0422 21:05:11.392322       1 probes.go:41] initialized health probe on port 8080
I0422 21:05:11.392351       1 probes.go:44] started health probe
I0422 21:05:11.392458       1 metrics.go:341] registered views for metric
I0422 21:05:11.392544       1 prometheus_exporter.go:21] starting Prometheus exporter
I0422 21:05:11.392561       1 metrics.go:347] registered and exported metrics on port 8888
I0422 21:05:11.392568       1 mic.go:244] initiating MIC Leader election
I0422 21:05:11.393053       1 leaderelection.go:243] attempting to acquire leader lease  default/aad-pod-identity-mic...
E0423 01:47:52.730839       1 leaderelection.go:325] error retrieving resource lock default/aad-pod-identity-mic: etcdserver: request timed out



resource "helm_release" "external-dns" {
    name          = "external-dns"
    repository    = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
    chart         = "external-dns"
    namespace     = "default"
    version       = "4.0.0"
  
  set {
      name  = "azure.cloud"
      value = "AzurePublicCloud"
  }
  
  #MyDnsResourceGroup
  set {
      name  = "azure.resourceGroup"
      value = data.azurerm_resource_group.dnsrg.name 
  }
  
  set {
      name  = "azure.tenantId"
      value = data.azurerm_subscription.currenttenantid.tenant_id
  }
  
  set {
      name  = "azure.subscriptionId"
      value = data.azurerm_subscription.currentSubscription.subscription_id
  }
  
  set {
      name    = "azure.userAssignedIdentityID"
      value   = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.external-dns-mi-tf.client_id
  }
  
  #Verbosity of the logs (options: panic, debug, info, warning, error, fatal, trace)
  set {
      name  = "logLevel"
      value = "trace" 
  }
  
  set {
      name  = "sources"
      value = "{service,ingress}"
  }
  
  set {
      name  = "domainFilters"
      value = "{${var.child_domain_prefix}.${lower(var.parent_domain)}}"
  }
  
  #DNS provider where the DNS records will be created (mandatory) (options: aws, azure, google, ...)
  set {
      name  = "provider"
      value = "azure"
  }
  
  #podLabels: {aadpodidbinding: <selector>} # selector you defined above in AzureIdentityBinding 
  set {
      name  = "podLabels.aadpodidbinding"
      value = "external-dns"
  }
  
  set {
      name = "azure.useManagedIdentityExtension"
      value = true
  }
}  



resource "helm_release" "aad-pod-identity" {
    name       = "aad-pod-identity"
    repository = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity/master/charts"
    chart      = "aad-pod-identity"
  }


  resource "helm_release" "ingress-azure" {
    name          = "ingress-azure"
    repository    = "https://appgwingress.blob.core.windows.net/ingress-azure-helm-package/"
    chart         = "ingress-azure"
    namespace     = "default"
    version       = "1.4.0"
  
  set {
      name        = "debug"
      value       = "true"
  }
  
  set {
      name        = "appgw.name"
      value       = data.azurerm_application_gateway.appgwpub.name
  }
  
  set {
      name        = "appgw.resourceGroup"
      value       = data.azurerm_resource_group.appgwpubrg.name
  }
  
  set {
      name        = "appgw.subscriptionId"
      value       = data.azurerm_subscription.currentSubscription.subscription_id
  }
  
  set {
      name        = "appgw.usePrivateIP"
      value       = "false"
  }
  
  set {
      name        = "armAuth.identityClientID"
      value       = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.agic-mi-tf.client_id
  }
  
  set {
      name        = "armAuth.identityResourceID"
      value       =  azurerm_user_assigned_identity.agic-mi-tf.id
  }
  
  set {
      name        = "armAuth.type"
      value       = "aadPodIdentity"
  }
  
  set {
      name        = "rbac.enabled"
      value       = "true"
  }
  
  set {
      name        = "verbosityLevel"
      value       = "5"
  }
  
  set {
      name        = "appgw.environment"
      value       = "AZUREPUBLICCLOUD"
  }
  
  set {
      name        = "metadata.name"
      value       = "ingress-azure"
  }
  
  }



PS C:\Workspace\tf\HelmOne> kubectl get azureassignedidentities
NAME                                                   AGE
ingress-azure-68c97fd496-qbptf-default-ingress-azure   23h


PS C:\Workspace\tf\HelmOne> kubectl get azureidentity
NAME                            AGE
ingress-azure                   23h
one-hi-sso-agic-mi-tf           23h
one-hi-sso-external-dns-mi-tf   23h


PS C:\Workspace\tf\HelmOne> kubectl edit azureidentity one-hi-sso-external-dns-mi-tf
apiVersion: aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1
kind: AzureIdentity
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1","kind":"AzureIdentity","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"one-hi-sso-external-dns-mi-tf","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"clientID":"f58e7c55-REDACTED-a6e358e53912","resourceID":"/subscriptions/8fb55161-REDACTED-3400b5271a8c/resourceGroups/one-hi-sso-kuberg-tf/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/one-hi-sso-external-dns-mi-tf","type":0}}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-04-22T20:44:42Z"
  generation: 2
  name: one-hi-sso-external-dns-mi-tf
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "432055"
  selfLink: /apis/aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/default/azureidentities/one-hi-sso-external-dns-mi-tf
  uid: f8e22fd9-REDACTED-6cdead0d7e22
spec:
  clientID: f58e7c55-REDACTED-a6e358e53912
  resourceID: /subscriptions/8fb55161-REDACTED-3400b5271a8c/resourceGroups/one-hi-sso-kuberg-tf/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/one-hi-sso-external-dns-mi-tf
  type: 0


PS C:\Workspace\tf\HelmOne> kubectl edit azureidentitybinding external-dns-mi-binding
apiVersion: aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1
kind: AzureIdentityBinding
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1","kind":"AzureIdentityBinding","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"external-dns-mi-binding","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"AzureIdentity":"one-hi-sso-external-dns-mi-tf","Selector":"external-dns"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-04-22T20:44:42Z"
  generation: 1
  name: external-dns-mi-binding
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "221101"
  selfLink: /apis/aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/default/azureidentitybindings/external-dns-mi-binding
  uid: f39e7418-e896-4b8e-b596-035cf4b66252
spec:
  AzureIdentity: one-hi-sso-external-dns-mi-tf
  Selector: external-dns



  resource "kubectl_manifest" "one-hi-sso-external-dns-mi-tf" {
    yaml_body = <<YAML
apiVersion: "aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1"  
kind: AzureIdentity
metadata:
  name: one-hi-sso-external-dns-mi-tf
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: 0
  resourceID: /subscriptions/8fb55161-REDACTED-3400b5271a8c/resourceGroups/one-hi-sso-kuberg-tf/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/one-hi-sso-external-dns-mi-tf
  clientID: f58e7c55-REDACTED-a6e358e53912
  YAML
}


resource "kubectl_manifest" "external-dns-mi-binding" {
    yaml_body = <<YAML
apiVersion: "aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1"
kind: AzureIdentityBinding
metadata:
  name: external-dns-mi-binding
spec:
  AzureIdentity: one-hi-sso-external-dns-mi-tf
  Selector: external-dns
YAML
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The managed identity I’m using was not added to the virtual machine scale set VMSS.  Once I added it, the binding works and the azureAssignedIdentity was created.

Also - I converted the AzureIdentity and Selector lines in my AzureIdentity YAML from upper case first letters to lower case first letters.

Correct:
azureIdentity:
selector:

Comment: What role definition did you give to the external-dns identity for the VMSS?

Comment: @grizzljt Managed Identity Operator and Virtual Machine Contributor.